# Can I create a light source via script in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write a little mod for Kerbal Space Program a game which uses Unity. I've got a class that is a child of `MonoBehaviour` which loads correctly and all. Part of this mod involves creating a new light source in the current scene. My question is as follows: is it possible for me to create a new Unity light source in the current scene using a script rather then the unity engine scene editor (which I obviously don't have access too as a modder).

Example of the sort of thing I'm looking for (I know it won't actually look anything like this but just to give you an idea of what I need)

`UnityEngine.getCurrentScene().createObject(new Light(pos, direction, color, strength));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the gameobject and add the light component:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        GameObject lightGameObject = new GameObject("The Light");
        Light lightComp = lightGameObject.AddComponent<Light>();
        lightComp.color = Color.blue;
        lightGameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, will this also add/load the GameObject you created into the active scene? Or will I need additional code for that? Sorry, I don't know much about Unity and I don't see any function there that explicitly adds the lightGameObject into the scene so if it does it in the background via constructor or something I wouldn't know.

Comment: You will need to use scene manager and then get the active scene, then run this code and it will add to the active scene. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html

Comment: Basically getting the active scene and adding the light is two separate parts, add the code above once you have the active scene and it will work.

Comment: Alright thanks! I'll accept. One more question if you don't mind: once I've retrieved the active scene, is there some function I need to call to link that `GameObject` to it or will just the retrieval function be needed?

Comment: Ah nvm, ignore that, should've done my reading first. "The currently active scene is the scene which will be used as the target for new GameObjects instantiated by scripts."